# not able to install visual studio 2022 using visual studio installer

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2022, vsinstaller

I have downloaded visual studio installer from "https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"
once its downloaded the installer file, when I click on install it says "Getting visual studio installer ready" and nothing happens after that. my internet connection is good and able to browse and download other files.

Tried this solution as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216897/visual-studio-2019-error-unable-to-download-instal.html and also tried after restarting machine. still having the same problem. you can find the screenshot for more information.

can anyone suggest what could be the issue. thanks

[image]

I could find the following log

[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] === Logging started: 2022/05/11 16:53:28 ===
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] Executable: C:\Users{username}\Downloads\vs_Community.exe v15.9.28307.1974
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] Directory 'C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\481074b13093fff3a2' has been selected for file extraction
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] Extracting files to: C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\481074b13093fff3a2
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] Extraction took 265 milliseconds
[5/11/2022, 16:53:28] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users{username}\Downloads\vs_Community.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users{username}\Downloads"'
[5/11/2022, 16:55:43] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/11/2022, 16:55:43] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138c
[5/11/2022, 16:55:43] === Logging stopped: 2022/05/11 16:55:43 ===

Answer (score 11):

in your host file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) insert this line and enjoy

```
93.184.215.201 download.visualstudio.microsoft.com
```

Comment: Here in South Korea, the domain name points to `192.229.232.200` according to `nslookup`-ing to several DNS servers. Adding the line to `hosts` solved the problem. It seems that this issue started from some problems in Microsoft's CDN.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently an issue with Microsoft's Installer Backend.
Have a look [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-Checking-for-up/10037277#T-N10037573) for the Microsoft ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off windows firewall and relaunch the visual studio installer, it works for me.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to install VS 2022 in a virtual machine. Later on ended up in getting an offline layout of the whole installer into a folder in host machine.

Try the below command to create an offline installer in the disk.

```
VisualStudioSetup.exe  --layout C:\VSLayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --includeRecommended --includeOptional
```

You will get the whole installer in a folder such as shown below.

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) link for more options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and the solution is as follows:

1. Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with [Notepad++](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.6/npp.8.6.Installer.x64.exe) as `Administrator` then add `93.184.215.201 download.visualstudio.microsoft.com`
2. Open `cmd prompt` as `Administrator` then type: `ipconfig /flushdns` then press `enter`.
3. Open `Visual Studio Installer`